# query optimization mariadb for nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I had a query that has three 'select' inside it. I guess it runs in O(n^3) and is not efficient at all, for return 10 rows is taking 6s, for 200 rows it takes 55s, and for 1000 rows it takes more than 3min, I really don't have any idea how could I make it better and faster.

mariadb version : 10.4.20-MariaDB

the query :

```
SELECT review.* FROM (SELECT review.* , 
                          (SELECT MIN(t2.id) FROM review t2 
                            WHERE t2.reviewcount = 0 
                            AND t2.fcid = review.fcid 
                            AND `userid` = :uid) as min_id
                      FROM review
                      WHERE reviewcount = 0 
                      AND `userid` = :uid) 
                      review
                      WHERE id = min_id AND deckid = :did LIMIT :nums;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish would all help.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just want to make this query faster or split, but I don't have any idea. Should I write the tables as well?

Comment: @AndyLester, Ok I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

review  should have a combined index(fcid,id,`userid`,deckid ,reviewcount)

The order of the columns is something you should test

```
SELECT r1.*       
FROM review r1
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT MIN(r2.id) min_id, fcid FROM review r2 
        WHERE t2.reviewcount = 0                             
        AND `userid` = :uid
        GROUP BY fcid) as r2
        ON r1.fcid = r2.fcid
  WHERE reviewcount = 0 
  AND `userid` = :uid
  AND  id = min_id AND deckid = :did 
  LIMIT :nums;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query simplified:

```
SELECT ...
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    review.*, 
    min(id) over (partition by userid, fcid) as min_id
  FROM review
  WHERE reviewcount = 0 
  AND userid = :uid
) r
WHERE id = min_id AND deckid = :did
LIMIT :nums;
```

You are looking for a user's reviews where the review count is zero. The appropriate index seems hence:

```
create index idx1 on review (userid, reviewcount);
```

This should suffice. If you want this a tad faster still, you can use a covering index instead:

```
create index idx2 on review (userid, reviewcount, fcid, id, deckid);
```